# CanExecute in MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, icommand

I am working on a Xamarin.Android application and I am using MvvmCross. Here in my code `DecreaseCommand` is not working:

```
public class CartItemViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private int quantity = 0;      

    public CartItemViewModel()
    {
        IncreaseCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteIncreaseCommand, CanExecuteIncreaseCommand);
        DecreaseCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteDecreaseCommand, CanExecuteDecreaseCommand);
        Delete = new MvxCommand (() => {Quantity++;});
    }        

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            quantity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Quantity");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
        }
    }

    public ICommand IncreaseCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand DecreaseCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand Delete { get; set; }


    private void ExecuteIncreaseCommand()
    {
         Quantity++;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteIncreaseCommand()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecuteDecreaseCommand()
    {
        Quantity--;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteDecreaseCommand()
    {
        return Quantity > 0;
    }


}
```

I suspect that `CanExecuteDecreaseCommand` is not firing, what could be wrong in this code?

Comment: How are you binding this? Doe the Increase command work?

Comment: Yes Increasecommand works.when in CanExecuteDecreaseCommand()   I put {return true} then it works fine.but when I put {Quantity !=0} it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` when you update your `Quantity` property.

Plus, you don't need to set a `CanExecute` that always returns true:

```
public class CartItemViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    private int quantity = 0;      

    public CartItemViewModel()
    {
        IncreaseCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteIncreaseCommand);
        DecreaseCommand = new MvxCommand(ExecuteDecreaseCommand, CanExecuteDecreaseCommand);
        Delete = new MvxCommand (() => {Quantity++;});
    }        

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            quantity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Quantity");
            RaisePropertyChanged("SubTotal");
            DecreaseCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public IMvxCommand IncreaseCommand { get; set; }
    public IMvxCommand DecreaseCommand { get; set; }
    public IMvxCommand Delete { get; set; }


    private void ExecuteIncreaseCommand()
    {
         Quantity++;
    }

    private void ExecuteDecreaseCommand()
    {
        Quantity--;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteDecreaseCommand()
    {
        return Quantity > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but error pops up with, System.Windows.Input.ICommand does not contain a definition for RaisCanExecuteChanged()

Comment: I have changed ICommand to IMvxCommand and It Works.Thank you so much.@wiliam Barbosa